# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: ajax, reactjs

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on
>   'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Getting the above error.

```
export const checkMobile = mobile => {
  return ajax(`/mobiles/search`, { method: "GET", body: mobile });
};

function ajax(uri, options = {}) {
  const defaultOptions = getDefaultOptions();

  options.method = options.method ? options.method : defaultOptions.method;

  if (!options.formType) {
    options.headers = options.headers
      ? options.headers
      : defaultOptions.headers;
  }

  options.credentials = options.credentials
    ? options.credentials
    : defaultOptions.credentials;

  if (options.body && !options.formType) {
    options.body = buildParam(options.body);
  }

  uri = uri.startsWith("/") ? uri : "/" + uri;
  console.log(`${CLIENT_URL}${uri}`);
  return fetch(`${CLIENT_URL}${uri}`, options).then(data => data.json());
}
```

Why I have not been allowed to add body data. Now how will I pass the data to the back end. I am using react in front end.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `options` object and ensure `body` is `undefined` if you're using `GET`.

`GET` requests should not be posting any data in the `body`. If you plan on sending data, you probably want to use `POST` as the method.

Comment: HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:8080) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:3000). Get this error in console.